# A bug regarding vertical scroll with mouse wheel

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollviewer, mousewheel

I'm faced with a trouble regarding vertical scroll with mouse wheel.

```
<ListBox x:Class="mynamespace.MyListBox"
         PreviewMouseWheel="listBox_OnPreviewMouseWheel"
         ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged="scrollViewer_OnScrollChanged">
</ListBox>

private void motionListBox_OnPreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Delta);
}

private void scrollViewer_OnScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.VerticalChange != 0.0)
    {                
        // Do something regarding vertical scroll
    }
}
```

When `MouseWheelEventArgs` `e.Delta` is `negative`, `ScrollChangedEventArgs e.VerticalChange` is `positive` (downward scrolling), and when `e.Delta` is `positive`, `e.VerticalChange` is `negative` (upward scrolling).

In my cases, however, this is sometimes opposite, i.e., even when `e.Delta` is `negative`, `e.VerticalChange` is `negative`, and mouse wheel direction does not coincide with vertical scroll direction.

This happens only when the vertical scroll bar is around the middle of the vertically scrollable area.

Could anyone tell me why this happens and how I can handle it?